# React/Redux project, Empty promise being returned from back-end via my api

Tags: reactjs, redux

https://github.com/ScorpIan555/snapshot

See repo above, I included that because I'm struggling to concisely explain the issue and cloning it might be more obvious for someone else, other than the fact that at lines 10/lines 11 of my actions/index.js file (code below), the promise is returning empty from the API connecting my front/backend.  I looked over my backend again, but it tested ok before.  Iv'e been over and over this and just can't find the issue.

Let me know what questions people have and I'll edit this post accordingly ...

My Account.js container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Register } from '../view'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import actions from '../../actions'

class Account extends Component {

    register(registration){
        //this.props.signup(registration)
      console.log('REGISTER:  '+ JSON.stringify(registration))
      this.props.signup(registration)
    }

    render() {

     return(
       <div>
                Account Container
                {
           //(currentUser == null) ?
           //<Register onRegister={this.register.bind(this)} onLogin={this.login.bind(this)} /> //:
           //<Register /> //:
           <Register onRegister={this.register.bind(this) } /> //:
                    //<h2>{currentUser.username}</h2>
                }

            </div>
     )
   }
}// class Account

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    account: state.account +
    console.log(JSON.stringify(state.account))
  }
}

const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    signup: (params) => dispatch(actions.signup(params))
  }
}
export default connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Account)
```

The signup prop is an action defined in my actions/index.js file:

```
import constants from '../constants'
import { APIManager } from '../utils'

export default {

    signup: (params) => {
        console.log('post receive:  '  +JSON.stringify(params))
        return (dispatch) => {
            APIManager
            .post('/account/register', params)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('RESPONSE : Actions index.js: '+JSON.stringify(response))
                 dispatch({
                    type: constants.CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED,
                    user: response.user
                 })
            })// .then(response => {
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('ERROR: '+err)
            })// .catch(err)
        }// return (dispatch)
    },

    updateCurrentLocation: (location) => {
        return {
            type: constants.CURRENT_LOCATION_CHANGED,
            location: location
        }
    },

    createPost: (params) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            APIManager
            .post('/api/post', params)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('RESPONSE: '+JSON.stringify(response))

                // dispatch({
                //  type: constants.POSTS_RECEIVED,
                //  posts: response.results
                // })
            })//.then(response => {
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('ERROR: '+err)
            })// .catch(err)
        }// return (dispatch)
    },

    fetchPosts: (params) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            APIManager
            .get('/api/post', null)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('RESPONSE: '+JSON.stringify(response))
                dispatch({
                    type: constants.POSTS_RECEIVED,
                    posts: response.results
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('ERROR: '+err)
            })// .catch(err)
        }// return (dispatch)
    },// fetchPosts,

    postsReceived: (posts) => {
        return {
            type: constants.POSTS_RECEIVED,
            posts: posts
        }

    }// postsReceived:

}// export default
```

My constants file where CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED is defined:

```
export default {

    CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED: 'CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED',

    CURRENT_LOCATION_CHANGED: 'CURRENT_LOCATION_CHANGED',

    POSTS_RECEIVED: 'POSTS_RECEIVED'

}
```

My Store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { postReducer, accountReducer } from '../reducers'

var store;

export default {
    configureStore: () => {
        const reducers = combineReducers({
            post: postReducer,
            account: accountReducer
        })

        store = createStore(
            reducers,
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )

        return store
    },

    currentStore: () => {
        return store
    }
}
```

accountReducer defined:

```
import constants from '../constants'

var initialState = {
  user: null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    let updated = Object.assign({}, state)

    switch (action.type){
    case constants.CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED:
console.log('CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED reducer0 : ' + JSON.stringify(updated))
      console.log('CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED reducer1 : ' + JSON.stringify(action))
      console.log('CURRENT_USER_RECEIVED reducer2 : ' + JSON.stringify(action.username))

      updated['user'] = action.user
      return updated

        default:
            return updated

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stupid mistake, wrong resource variable